# Eclipse - subversive custom checkout projectname / folder

Tags: eclipse, subversive, svnkit

i'm using the new release of eclipse (Indigo). I've installed subversive svn connector (with SVNKit 1.3.5).

The problem is when checking out from a repository, I cannot select my local folder anymore where to export to. In svn i have my repository root | myprojectname | dev_source | trunk, tags, branches.

When I check out my project name in eclipse automaticly becomes dev_source. I also don't want to use myprojectname, but a custom project name.

It there a sollution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rename your project right click on the project name and select 'Rename' from the Project Explorer View in your eclipse.

If you have already checked out the source from SVN, you can move the source to your own location, create a new Eclipse workspace or delete the eclipse project (not the contents) and import as a project back again. There will be an option to use your own name during the import too.

Cheers!!!

Comment: renaming the project also renames the root folder of the project. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!